# Monodromy Groups of Differential Equations

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I have heard that monodromy groups and analytic continuation can be used to construct new solutions to a differential equation from a particular solution. What references (textbook, or papers) could I read to learn more about this topic, and if you happen to know a good example, I would love to hear it.

I have made some progress on finding references for this, but the most helpful in terms of explicit computation and a derivation of monodromy strictly from a differential equation is 
"Black Hole Scattering from Monodromy" by Castro, Lapan, Maloney, and Rodriguez from Harvard and McGill. In particular, I find the derivation in Section 2.1 very helpful and would be looking for a more detailed explanation of computing monodromy matrix representations using analytic continuations, Wilson loops, etc.

Comment: Maybe you want to peruse: http://www.amazon.com/Monodromy-Group-Monografie-Matematyczne/dp/3764375353